# videojs multiple audio languages

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, video.js

how can I add switchable audio tracks within `videojs` , I was trying by doing this :

```
 <video id="l2e-video" muted class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls width="640" height="264" data-setup="" mediagroup="lang_tracks">
                <source src="http://localhost/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                <track src="http://localhost/1.mp3" kind="descriptions" type="audio/mp3" srclang="en" label="English">
                <track src="http://localhost/1.mp3" kind="descriptions" type="audio/mp3" srclang="ar" label="Arabic">

        </video>
```

but when I'm trying to load it , it errors :

```
Text Track parsing errors for http://localhost/1.mp3

{name: "ParsingError", code: 0, message: "Malformed WebVTT signature."}
```

I have no clue how it says `Text track` when am explicitly setting the `type` to `audio` , how would I achieve having a video with multiple languages?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I have ended up doing is , having one `<video>` without any sound/voice, and multiple `<audio>` with different languages , and I sync the video with the audio, here is an implementation using `Angular` it can be ported to any other framework easily :-

HTML:

```
  <div class="video-container">
                            <video id="l2e-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls data-setup="" mediagroup="lang_tracks">
                            </video>
                            <audio id="l2e-audio" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" style="display:none"></audio>
    </div>
```

TypeScript/Javascript:

```
import { Video } from './../../models/video';
import { Point } from './../../models/point';
import { Audio } from "./../../models/audio";
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';



/*NOTES: add overlay for the markers*/

@Component({
    selector: 'videojs',
    templateUrl: './videojs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./videojs.component.scss']
})
export class VideojsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    video: any = videojs;
    audio: any = videojs;
    prevButton: any = {};

    qualities: Array<Video> = [];
    audioLangs: Array<Audio> = [];


    constructor() {
    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.qualities = [
            { src: "http://localhost/1.mp4", type: "video/mp4", label: "SD" },
            { src: "http://localhost/1.mp4", type: "video/mp4", label: "HD" },
        ];
        this.audioLangs = [
            { src: 'http://localhost/en.m4a', type: 'audio/mp3', label: "English" },
            { src: 'http://localhost/ar.m4a', type: 'audio/mp3', label: "Arabic" }
        ];
        
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.audio = videojs('l2e-audio', {});

        //TODO:: save video lang ,
        this.audio.src(this.audioLangs[0]); //to be changed dynamic

        this.video = videojs('l2e-video', {
            fluid: true,
            plugins: {
            
                videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
                    default: 'HD',
                    dynamicLabel: true
                }
            }
        });

        this.video.updateSrc(this.qualities);


        this.Sync(this.video, this.audio);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.video.dispose();
    }




    ChangeLang(index) {
        this.audio.src(this.audioLangs[index]);
        this.audio.play();
        this.audio.currentTime(this.video.currentTime());
    }

    private Sync(video, audio) {

        this.video.on('timeupdate', () => {
            if (!this.video.paused())
                return;
            this.audio.trigger('timeupdate');
        });
        this.video.on('seeking', () => {
            this.audio.currentTime(this.video.currentTime());
        });
        this.video.on('volumechange', () => {
            if (this.video.muted()) {
                this.audio.muted(true);
            } else {
                this.audio.muted(false);
            }

            this.audio.volume(this.video.volume());
        });
        this.video.on('play', () => {
            this.audio.play();
        });
        this.video.on('pause', () => {
            this.audio.pause();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue how it says `Text track` when am explicitly setting the
>   `type` to `audio`

`type` is not a valid attribute for `<track>` element. [`<track>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) element `src` attribute value should point to a valid `.vtt` file, not an `"audio/*"` file.

`<track>` element does not load a list of media resources to be played.

You can create a `<select>` element with `<option>` values set to path to media resource. At `change` event of `select` element set `<video>` `.src` to `.value` of selected `option`.

Comment: I wanna change the audio track not the video it'self

Comment: @Abanoub Do you mean the audio track of the video that is playing?

Comment: yeah I wanna the user to switch the playing audio

Comment: @Abanoub Have you tried approach described at Answer?

Comment: Any porgress on this? If yes then can you please add an answer

Comment: @ApurvG Have you created valid `.vtt` files?

Comment: Yes. I have .vtt files

Comment: Then the approach at Answer should provide a solution. You can use `<select>` element with `<option>` child elements set to the `<track>` which should be used, remove sibling `<track>` element